# Stored Proc run manually differs from run via job

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored proc which when run manually, produces expected results. When run by the Job Agent, I get very different results and I cannot work out why. The issue relates to the following

```
declare @date as date
set @date=case datepart(dw,getdate())
when 1 then GETDATE()-3 --Monday so use Friday
when 7 then GETDATE()-2 --Sunday so use Friday
else GETDATE()-1 end
print @date
```

It appears that when run as a job, `@date` is being set to `GETDATE()-1` regardless on a Monday. But appears to be set to `GETDATE()-2` correctly on a Sunday....

What have I cocked up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SET DATEFIRST https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx

One possible reason could be that the job login has a different setting than your own login.

Comment: I cannot believe I am so stupid. Thanks. That's exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I guess the server on which your are running the job results in 1 when you execute select datepart(dw,getdate()) .